# Using intent and bundle for integers in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-bundle

Say I wanted to pass data from one activity/class to the other involving an integer data type. Here's what I have for the MainActivity (first) class so far:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    final int x = 3;
    i.putExtra("new variable", x);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

For the receiving class, SecondActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    Bundle i = getIntent().getExtras();
    String value = i.getString("new variable");
    tvResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);
    tvResult.setText(value);
}
```

However, SecondActivity shows up with nothing on the second screen... Could it perhaps be because I need to convert value to an int first?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to pass data from one activity/class to the other involving
>   an integer data type...

`x` is `int` but in `SecondActivity` `i.getString` is used to get data from `Bundle` which return `String` instead of int.

Use `Bundle.getInt` to get `int` from `Bundle`.

```
int value = i.getInt("new variable");
```

Also use `String.valueOf` for showing `int` in `TextView` as:

```
tvResult.setText(String.valueOf(value));
```

Comment: Thanks, I greatly appreciate it!